# Python parent class access to child private variables

Tags: python, oop, class, inheritance

The following code generates an error:

```
class A(object):
    def say_something(self):
        print(self.foo)
        print(self.__bar)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'hello'
        self.__bar = 'world'

test = B()
test.say_something()
```

Printing of 'hello' is successful but 'world' generates the following error:

```
    print(self.__bar)
```

> AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_A__bar'

I am surprised by this, I would like my parent class to have a method which has access to a private attribute its children are guaranteed to have. Is there some standard way of solving this problem?

Comment: You may find the following question helpful: [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `self._B__something` to access it. However, this is not what yuo should do. The proper solution is renaming `__bar` to `_bar`.

The idea behind the [double-underscore name mangling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) is to avoid conflicts with subclasses/superclasses - it's not meant to be used for private variables. If a variable should be considered private/internal, prefix it with a single underscore. This does not cause any special treatment but every python developer will know that it's not part of the public API of the class/module containing that variable.

Comment: Exactly.  The intention of the name mangling mechanism is to get exactly the behavior the OP is seeing here.  It is meant to make a member element be linked to 1 and only 1 scope.

Comment: Got it. I found the same thing you are saying here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html I suppose I'm still a bit uncomfortable with the idea of nothing being truly private.

Comment: Well, even in a language with "real" private variables there are always ways (reflection or messing around with the memory) to access them. Python simply assumes programmers are smart so it doesn't truly enforce private variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's name mangling.  Any member that starts with double underscores gets name mangled in Python.  Your code would work with any other members, as long as they didn't start with double underscore.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are missing something in your code.. I don't see __bar in either class A or class B..

Comment: On StackOverflow we use proper english, i.e. "you" and "are" instead of "u" and "r".