# why is subclass accessing superclass' attribute inspite of having its own attribute of same name when that attribute is declared private?

Tags: python, oop

I have a parent class **Animal** and child class **Dog**. I wanted to create 1 instance of each and print the their *count*. Here is the working code:

```
class Animal:
  count=0
  def __init__(self):
     Animal.count+=1
  @classmethod
  def getCount(cls):
     return cls.count

class Dog (Animal):
  count=0
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    Dog.count+=1

 a1=Animal()
 print(Animal.getCount(),Dog.getCount())
 d1=Dog()
 print(Animal.getCount(),Dog.getCount())
```

It prints:
 
1 0
2 1

which is correct as there are 2 animals but only 1 of them is dog.
The problem occurs when i create *count* variable as private *__count* without changing any other piece of code.

```
class Animal:
  __count=0
  def __init__(self):
    Animal.__count+=1
  @classmethod
  def getCount(cls):
    return cls.__count

class Dog (Animal):
  __count=0
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    Dog.__count+=1

a1=Animal()
print(Animal.getCount(),Dog.getCount())
d1=Dog()
print(Animal.getCount(),Dog.getCount())
```

Now, it prints:
 
1 1
2 2

Seems like **Dog** class is only accessing the **Animal's** *__count*.
 **Can you detect  the bug in the code?**

Comment: you use a `@classmethod` so everything that uses that class, which is both of your subclasses, will use it.

Comment: Very closely related: [Python parent class access to child private variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/10807692)

Answer (score 4):

### The short answer

When an attribute is *private*, like `__count`, that means it can only be accessed from **within the same class**. `Animal.__count` can only be accessed within `Animal`, and `Dog.__count` can only be accessed within `Dog`.

Because `getCount` is defined in `Animal`, it only has access to `Animal.__count`, so that's what it returns.

If you want to access a "private" variable of a subclass, use a single underscore prefix like `_count`.

Related reading:

- [Python parent class access to child private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10807692)
- [The official python documentation on private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

### Going into detail

Private variables are implemented through a mechanism called *name mangling*. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called *name mangling*. **Any
>   identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.** This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

What this means is that your code is translated to this:

```
class Animal:
    _Animal__count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Animal._Animal__count += 1

    @classmethod
    def getCount(cls):
        return cls._Animal__count

class Dog(Animal):
    _Dog__count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Dog._Dog__count += 1
```

If you look at it like this, it's obvious that `getCount` cannot access `Dog`'s `__count` variable.

Comment: *it can only be accessed from within the same class* - this is not right. Please see my answer.

Comment: getCount is defined in Animal but its also inherited in Dog. There is another __count defined in Dog. So shouldn't Dog.getCount()  return Dog's __count?

Comment: @irootaku Inheriting a method doesn't make a copy of it. It's defined in `Animal`, so it can't access private `Dog` attributes. For a bit more detail, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) done by Python when any class level variable starts with at least two underscores, and have at most one underscore at the end.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    __bar = 10
```

Now, `Foo.__bar` can be accessed outside of the `Foo` class as `Foo._Foo__bar`.

---

In your case, you would be better off simply using a single underscore i.e. `_count` as variable name which indicates the users that the name is meant to be used privately only.

---

If you want to follow the abtitious route and keep your current structure, you can define the superclass' `getCount` method to return values based on the class it's called from:

```
In [1720]: class Animal: 
      ...:     __count=0 
      ...:     def __init__(self): 
      ...:         Animal.__count += 1

      ...:     @classmethod 
      ...:     def getCount(cls):     
      ...:         return cls.__count if cls.__name__ == 'Animal' else getattr(cls, f'_{cls.__name__}__count')
```

---

As an aside, you might want to use *snake_case* for method names e.g. `get_count`, and 4 spaces for indenting.